# How do I fix "datasource serviceImpl.error_0009" in pentaho?

Tags: pentaho

I log into pentaho using the administrator's username and password, then go into file > new > datasource select "SQL QUERY", then type in my database and test it for database connection, it is successful. When I try to test the new datasource with the sql query, I type in "`select 1 from mytable`" and it gives me this error:

> datasourceServiceImpl.error_0009
>   query validation failed: query validation failed {0}

This is all that it is giving me and I don't know how to fix this.

I have biserver-ce-5.1.0.0-752 running

Comment: Do you get the same error if you try with: 'SELECT 1'?

Comment: yes I get the same error.

Comment: What about 'Select 1' query on any other data source?

Comment: Still does not work, the only other data source available right now would be the example but it does not work either.

Comment: I saw it once here: http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/BISERVER-7193 . It has never happend to me so I do not how to answer especially when it's a known bug which reappears in version 5. I would try to 'fix' it in next order: 1. Restart database 2. Restart db server, 3. restart BI Server,4. restart VM where BI Server runs, 5. Reinstall Pentaho Stack 6. Modify priveledges to owner:group

Comment: Did you manage to fix it? I have the same error, also with select 1 and with other data sources. The mysql connection was succesful and it can show the tables. Updating the mysql jar didn't help.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed the issue by removing ";" at the end of my query.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @BenFortune It does attempt to answer the question. If it's wrong downvote it, don't flag.

Comment: @Drux Why should he? (see my comment above)

Comment: In 2019 - still a valid answer. And still unbelievable, that this is the error cause.

Answer (score 3):

Stop the server.
Change the mysql driver folder `.. \ tomcat \ lib "mysql-connector-java-5.1.17.jar"` the driver `"mysql-connector-java-5.1.25-bin.jar"`.
Restart the server and it will work.

Comment: Can I get some clarification on this? There seem to be some words missing...  I don't have any files named "mysql..." in the `/Pentaho/server/pentaho-server/tomcat/lib` folder.

Comment: added latest mysql j connector jar into <pre>/Pentaho/server/pentaho-server/tomcat/lib and it started working.  This main problem is with 
 mysql j/connector I am using 5.1.42.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error and found that it was as simple as having 2 columns named the same thing in my SELECT statement.

Answer (score -1):

Install mysql-connector-java-gpl-x.x.x.msi
Put into lib folder mysql-connector-java-x.x.x.jar